# What's wrong with my DDL statement?

Tags: mariadb, ddl

I am trying to run:

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`users` text NOT NULL,
`password` text NOT NULL,
`ip` text NOT NULL,
`status`text NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM;
```

I just can't seem to find the error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 8
```

Comment: What did you find when you checked the manual as suggested by the error message?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Nothing because I wouldn't know where to look..

Comment: I would start with the chapter "SQL commands" in the manual: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/

Answer (score 3):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11471133/470530), replace TYPE=MYISAM with ENGINE=MYISAM.

This used to be acceptable syntax, but has been deprecated and removed in 5.5 (from the same thread).